# Facebook connect. Works in Firefox/Internet Explorer, not in Chrome/Safari/Opera

Tags: javascript, facebook

I have an app wich is an index.php file with javascript and when the user is logged in the javascript loads the content of the page which is stored in content.php

(k, I've figured out that it works in safari if the user has allowed popups. I get the same error with firefox. So can popup windows be the enemy? How can i rewrite this to ton use popups?)

Index.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My app</title>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css"/>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="fb-root"></div>
        <script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.validationEngine.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.validationEngine-en.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/validationEngine.jquery.css" type="text/css"/>
        <script src="js/functions.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

functions.js:

```
FB.init({
    appId  : '123456789',
    status : true, // check login status
    cookie : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
    xfbml  : true  // parse XFBML
});

FB.login(function(response) {
    if (response.session) {
        if (response.perms) {
            $.get("content.php", {get: "form"}, function(data){
                $('body').append(data);
            });     
        } else {
            top.location.href="http://example.com";
        }
    } else {
        top.location.href="http://www.example.com";
    }
}, {perms:'publish_stream'});
```

It works in Firefox and Internet Explorer but in Chrome, Safari and Opera it doesn't.
I got this error in Chrome with the javascript debug:

```
Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL https://www.facebook.com/login.php?api_key=123456789&skip_api_login=1&display=popup&cancel_url=http%3A%2F%2Fstatic.ak.fbcdn.net%2Fconnect%2Fxd_proxy.php%3Fversion%3D0%23cb%3Df13bcfbe1%26origin%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fexample.com%252Ff1fd4b982c%26relation%3Dopener%26transport%3Dpostmessage%26frame%3Df206b2144c%26result%3D%2522xxRESULTTOKENxx%2522&fbconnect=0&next=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fdialog%2Fpermissions.request%3F_path%3Dpermissions.request%26app_id%3D152123456789%26redirect_uri%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fstatic.ak.fbcdn.net%252Fconnect%252Fxd_proxy.php%253Fversion%253D0%2523cb%253Df13bcfbe1%2526origin%253Dhttp%25253A%25252F%25252Fexample.com%25252Ff1fd4b982c%2526relation%253Dopener%2526transport%253Dpostmessage%2526frame%253Df206b2144c%2526result%253D%252522xxRESULTTOKENxx%252522%26sdk%3Djoey%26display%3Dpopup%26api_key%3D123456789%26fbconnect%3D0%26locale%3Den_US%26method%3Dpermissions.request%26perms%3Dpublish_stream%26return_session%3D1%26session_version%3D3%26from_login%3D1&rcount=1 from frame with URL http://example.com/myfacebookapp/. Domains, protocols and ports must match.
```

In Opera it gets stuck on a popup window (popup allowed) with this url:

```
http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/connect/xd_proxy.php?version=0#cb=f5132b51b60fbe&origin=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Ff10a57ba8d445c&relation=opener&transport=flash&frame=f19023256ffd8&result=%7B%22perms%22%3A%22publish_stream%22%2C%22selected_profiles%22%3A1245738876%2C%22session%22%3A%22%7B%5C%22session_key%5C%22%3A%5C%222.buXjHddfcr_xKQHVeu_FXw__.3600.1299679200-1245738876%5C%22%2C%5C%22uid%5C%22%3A%5C%221245738876%5C%22%2C%5C%22expires%5C%22%3A1299679200%2C%5C%22secret%5C%22%3A%5C%22glwIAcpeG0HDT__0z1QI3g__%5C%22%2C%5C%22access_token%5C%22%3A%5C%22152384968151443%7C2.buXjHdcfcr_xKQHVeu_FXw__.3600.1299679100-1245738876%7CdyZCE5trqgMkU0HSzSorX3jqbIs%5C%22%2C%5C%22sig%5C%22%3A%5C%228724dd80df9f16e7c3a2ce1b06f8d1e1%5C%22%7D%22%7D
```

So my question is: How can I get this to work in all browsers (Firefox, IE, Chrome & safari preferably)?

(edit: I have changed the urls and removed codes and urls to my app)

Answer (score 0):

I also had a similarly bad experience with the popups. Eventually I moved away from the client flow model you are using, to the server flow model, where the server does the redirecting.

(I never followed this through with Javascript, but what I can see in the docs, there does not seem to be an option to turn off the popup. http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/fb.login/)

I can't provide you with a php example, as my stuff is in .NET but I think it should work in a similar way for you:

1. Create a link to your FB login page: e.g. FBLogin.php
2. This page then uses a library (facebook php sdk?) to help create the login url for facebook with a return url (e.g. FBAuthorize.php) to your site.  You will then be redirected to the facebooke login url.
3. After successfully authentication on FB, you will be sent back the FBAuthorize.php page, where the magic token exchanging should be handled by the library.

No popup, no javascript.

Comment: Thanks. I have thought of going back to php (I used it in the beginning but didn't get to work so I tried js). But the problem is I don't have much time left until deadline. :/